# LibreOffice 6.4.4.2 can't open file under symbolic link

Tags: libreoffice

I installed LibreOffice 6.4.4.2 from Software center (Ubuntu 20.04).

I tried to open file under a symbolic link, but I can't open it because symbolic link directory looks like a file.

How do I open a file in a directory below the symbolic link.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRW1l.jpg

This is a LibreOffice 6.4.4.2 issue only.
Other software, such as Firefox, does not occur.

settings are as follows

```
home: /home/fennec
link: ln -s /var/local/user/fennec /home/fennec/Data

Parmission:
lrwxrwxrwx   1 fennec fennec   22  2月 11  2018 Data -> /var/local/user/fennec
drwxr-xr-x  15 fennec fennec 4096 10月 27  2019 /var/local/user/fennec

Process:
fennec     36583   14487  0 01:02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /snap/libreoffice/180/libreoffice.wrapper --calc
fennec     36662   36583  0 01:02 ?        00:00:10 /snap/libreoffice/180/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --calc
fennec     37376   35778  0 01:38 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto libre
```

Comment: It's not LibreOffice, it's the Snap. Snaps can open files only from certain directories, like /home/$YOU. Their AppArmor confinement prevents them from opening files in /var. It's a security feature. You can either learn more about Snap security, or you can install the .deb version instead.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Software Center is limited to Snap packages. These are special containers with certain limitations.

Comment: @lev258 the deb version is in the Ubuntu repositories. It's still just an apt away. If it's not reflected in Ubuntu Software, that seems a separate bug.

Comment: It's not a bug. The Software Center is now limited to Snap. Of course you can find everything else with apt or Synaptic.

Comment: user535733 , lev258 
Thank you for the quick and clear answer. I got to understand it's Snap specification. I will use deb version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a current issue, after 4 years?  Why would the default install method cause files to not work behind symbolic links?

LibreOffice 7.6.3.2 from Ubuntu Software gnome gui, kubuntu 22.04 LTS, new setup on a new computer.  I keep my user files on a separate partition, easy to backup and move, with symbolic links put in the new OS install user home dir, pointing to the directories from the other partition mount.

Uninstall LibreOffice from the Ubuntu Software (snap) install system, then

```
$ sudo apt install libreoffice
```

and now it's fine.   (apt installed 7.3.7.2 LibreOffice, Ubuntu package version:  1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4)

Glad it was easy to fix, but seems like an embarrassing problem to have with something so widely used.